# How can I call Lua scripts from a C program?

Tags: c, lua

I have 2 lua scripts. One require another one. So how can I call it from a C program?

For example:

main.lua

```
local foo = require "foo"

function main()
    foo.bar()
end

main()
```

foo.lua

```
function bar( )
    io.write("hello, world!\n")
end
```

And this is my C program:

```
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int status, result;
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    status = luaL_loadfile(L, "main.lua");
    if (status) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load file: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    result = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to run script: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

It throws a runtime error:

> Failed to run script: main.lua:130: module 'foo' not found:   no field
>   package.preload['foo']    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/foo.lua'  no
>   file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/foo/init.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/foo.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/foo/init.lua'     no file './foo.lua'     no file
>   './foo/init.lua'  no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/foo.so'     no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'   no file './foo.so'

I think it is because foo.lua is not loaded into the lua virtual machine, but I can't find API like load files or do files. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, your `foo.lua` is wrong, change it to:

```
local foo = {}

function foo.bar()
    io.write("Hello World!\n")
end

return foo
```

and it works:

```
$ ls
foo.lua  luabr.c  main.lua
BladeMight ~/lua/tests/605
$ gcc luabr.c -llua && ./a
Hello World!
```

** **luabr.c** is your C program code.